# Loading data into teradata using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, teradata

I want to load data from SQL to Teradata using SSIS. As per my R&D I got to know that we can use third party tool which is provided in the link,   http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-connect/ssis-connectors-for-oracle-and-teradata

IS there any other way to load the data into **Teradata** using **SSIS**??

Thanks
Venky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Teradata OLE DB Provider](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/ole-db-provider). With this driver you can connect as you'd do with SQL Server or any other DB, and load the data as usual.

Be aware that there's only a 32 bit version for this driver. So, you'll rather install a 32 bit version of SSIS, or you'll have to take this into account:

[Quick Reference: SSIS in 32- and 64-bits](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com.es/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html)